# GUI for Dialog-design for WiX

Tags: wix

WiX is great in that there is no GUI, you just write the installer you want it to be. No fiddling with GUI-wizards!

However, drawing GUI is actually one thing I prefer to use a GUI for.

So, is there any Dialog-drawing program which exports WiX-data?
(I suppose else-wise perhaps I could transform what Visual Studio's forms editor does to WiX-XML.)

/L

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can try [WixEdit](http://wixedit.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I highly recommend this installer. It walks you through the step of creating an installer from scratch. It may be out of date, but you can always use SharpDevelop to finish where it left off.

Comment: Hasn't been updated since March 2011.

Comment: [Changelog](https://wixedit.github.io/changelog/) shows it's been updated (October 14, 2021 at time of writing).

Answer (score 54):

I created a full list of editors for WiX here: https://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2007/11/20/wix-editors/ (which is amazingly still up to date)

Comment: PLEASE keep this list updated. :)

Comment: Something similar like WixEdit should be default in Visual Studio 2015...

Answer (score 9):

SharpDevelop also has built-in capabilities for laying out a WiX dialog.  I prefer it over WixEdit.

Comment: This is what I was never able to achieve. Hopefully, it would be better in latest versions.

Answer (score 5):

this is excellent GUI IDE and it is open source.....

try this...
http://community.sharpdevelop.net/blogs/mattward/archive/2006/09/17/WixIntegration.aspx

download IDE from here:

http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/Download/

Answer (score 3):

If you use Visual Studio 2008/2010 and want to install an application that requires .NET framework you might be interested in having a look at [SharpSetup](http://sharpsetup.eu/). It allows you to graphically edit installer UI as WinForms controls (and use VS designer for that).