# setup and deployment vs2010 project Configure Open with My application

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, registry

**FIRST**

I am writing a setup and deployment project in vs2010 and would like to know how can I make certain files open with my application. In other-words I want ( after installation) to be able to right click a specific file and open it with my app.

**SECOND**
I don't want to replace the default program associated with this files but I just what my app to appear in the list of apps to choose from when a specific file is right clicked

Now I know I have to change the registry by adding/changing key(s) but I don't know which ones and don't what to change the wrong ones. So far I have figured out how to add the keys (sort of) in this stack overflow question

[Installer Custom Action problem - can't write to register key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782492/installer-custom-action-problem-cant-write-to-register-key)

Comment: I thought I would mention that setup and deployment projects have been discontinued from vs2012 on-wards. So this is a dead-end path if you plan to upgrade.

Comment: @PeterR This is a small personal non-commercial program to be used by me and friends ( am a student) so that's not an issue to me.and whats the alternative then?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9135934/please-tell-me-there-is-a-good-alternative-to-install-shield