# installer to replace installShield

Tags: installation, installshield

I need a recommendation for an installer.
I was using InstallShield but unfortunately it was a demo version that only allowed me to get a quick start.
Now I need to switch to an installer that is open source and allows to:

- create environment variables on user's computer
- add files to a giving path
- create .exe (via Release Wizard in IstallShield)

I came across tools like NSIS but I am not sure it has the same features as InstallShield.

Please advice!
Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a good alternative to Install Shield?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9135934/is-there-a-good-alternative-to-install-shield)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Wix tool. It is open source and it has most of the capability of Installshield. Only problem with WiX is there would be a learning curve of MSI technology and WiX itself.