# Good WiX editor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, deployment, wix

I'm currently working on a project that uses WiX to create an MSI. I've used WiXEdit on Sourceforge in the past for managing the files that get included in the WiX project as it's slightly easier than manipulating the XML directly but it's still a bit clunky. Does anyone know of a better tool for managing the files included in a WiX project or a better alternative for creating an MSI to deploy an MVC application?

Comment: The WiXEdit workflow isn't straight. But finally I got all files in my MSI. Do you have specific problems where you could need a hint?

Comment: why not use Visual Studio 2012? It really good with the WIX 3.7 plugin

Comment: @harper - it's not so much that we have a specific issue, it's more that we are calling the package target during the website build and creating the WiX package based on everything that's deployed there. We would prefer to be able to cherry-pick which assets are included and which are not. WiXEdit is very manual and it's easy to miss stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to consider IsWiX ( CodePlex )

Here's a recent blog article with a YouTube video showing how to create a stub windows service, create an installer for it and check it into TFS SaaS for CI builds in < 10 minutes.

http://blog.iswix.com/2013/01/iswix-20130134-released.html

The same patterns can be used to handle whatever MVC can throw at you. ( Tweak the MSBuild proj to publish to a local folder and use IsWiX to cherry pick the files from that folder into your WXS. )

An hour on a webex together would probably bring tons of clarity.

Answer (score 2):

i'm using Visual studio 2012 with Wix 3.7 . but you can also look here [GUI for Dialog-design for WiX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2569707/gui-for-dialog-design-for-wix)

Comment: Cheers for the link - will have a good look through there tomorrow

Answer (score 2):

Here is a list of editors: http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2007/11/20/WiX-editors. The WiX v2.0 editors are not interesting but the WiX v3.0 editors is still relevant.

Comment: Awesome - cheers Rob, will have a look through