# Create a web application setup to import application in local IIS

Tags: c#, .net, iis, installshield

I have a C# web application which I am able to launch using Visual Studio 2012 in which I developed it. However, I want to create a setup for this application (which is not available in Visual Studio 2012). Therefore, I tried using the Installshield setup creation utility. I could successfully build the setup after using the pointers in:

http://ultidev.com/Forums/yaf_postsm3358_Building-UWSASP-NET-app-installation-with-InstallShield.aspx

Now I am not sure how to have it imported into the IIS manager so I can directly go and browse the my web application  URL after successfully installing the setup.exe.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you trying to install a web application with InstallShield? Any reason in particular? It's usually easier to deploy/publish a website rather than installing it

Comment: Installshield was an option I considered. I am able to create a zipped folder for the website, ready to be deployed. The step that I want to automate is. to be able to make it a website under the "default Web Site"in local IIS manager on any machine I want. I was thinking I could achieve this via a msi creation, but that seems to be not straight forward on VS 2012. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you looked at WiX? I asked a question about it a while back on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14587181/good-wix-editor

Answer (score 0):

Recently i ran on a same problem, so here is what i found interesting regarding your question.

There is a setup explanation here:
[www.wavepointstudios.net/Msi2011/How-to-Install-a-Web-Application.aspx](http://www.wavepointstudios.net/Msi2011/How-to-Install-a-Web-Application.aspx)